# Code to throw object doesn't gain any height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am trying to instantiate and throw objects into the air on mouse clicks.  The objects will spawn as expected but do not gain any height on the throw.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class shooter : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject powercell; //link to the powerCell prefab
public GameObject Dynamite; // same as above but for dyno
public int no_cell; //number of powerCell owned
public int no_Dynamite; // same as above but for dyno
public AudioClip throwSound; //throw sound
public float throwSpeed = 20;//throw speed


void Start()
{
    no_Dynamite = 0; // no dynos on spawn
    no_cell = 10000; // one cell on spawn
}

public void Update()
{
    //if left control (fire1) pressed, and we still have at least 1 cell
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && no_cell > 0)
    {
        no_cell--; //reduce the cell
                   //play throw sound
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(throwSound, transform.position);
        //instantaite the power cel as game object
        GameObject cell = Instantiate(powercell, transform.position,
        transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        //ask physics engine to ignore collison between
        //power cell and our FPSControler
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(transform.root.GetComponent<Collider>(),
        cell.GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
        //give the powerCell a velocity so that it moves forward
        cell.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * throwSpeed;
    }


    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2") && no_Dynamite > 0)
    {
        no_Dynamite--; //reduce the cell
                       //play throw sound
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(throwSound, transform.position);
        //instantaite the power cel as game object
        GameObject Dyn = Instantiate(Dynamite, transform.position,
        transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        //ask physics engine to ignore collison between
        //power cell and our FPSControler
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(transform.root.GetComponent<Collider>(),
        Dyn.GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
        //give the powerCell a velocity so that it moves forward
        Dyn.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * throwSpeed;
    }
}

//
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Bomb") // give us cells when we pick up the collectable
    {
        no_Dynamite = 3; ; //increment that boi
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "stopped working"? u didn't change anything and it doesn't do what you expect? what is happening? do you even get to the condition? maybe no_cell is never > 0?

Comment: @ZivWeissman i simply opened up the project after i went to sleep and it stopped working, no explanation as to why. Ill post the code for the whole Script if that helps anymore?

Comment: Are you looking upwards at all when you throw it? Also, does throwing cells work properly? Also, please be more descriptive than "stopped working". You say it doesn't "gain any height" but does that mean that gravity still works on it?

Comment: @Ruzihm sorry im new to this mostly. I have tried looking up and it just still slides across the floor when i throw it. Gravity does still work on the object too, and the cells being thrown work perfectly, except they always just slide along the floor when thrown

Comment: It's strange that your cells can throw but your dynamites can't. Do you have any scripts on your Dynamite objects? Also, are you being sure to save all changes to your scripts before trying to play the scene?

Comment: Both of them can throw, neither of them gain any height on the throw. The scripts i have for my Dynamite is just a simple collision detection so the play can pick it up, and another explosion one

Comment: Is there any code where you change the rotation or of your `Shooter` ?

Comment: No the only sort of rotation code i have is a standalone script that just tells whatever its attached to to rotate, but it isn't attached to shooter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an upwards component to the thrown object's velocity. If you know how much upwards you want on a scale of `0` to `1`, you can use `Vector3.Slerp` to figure out the direction you need.

```
// give the dynamite a velocity so that it moves up + forward
Rigidbody dynamiteRB = Dyn.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

float upness = 0.5f; // 0f = horizontal ~ 1f = vertical
Vector3 throwDirection = Vector3.Slerp(
        transform.forward, 
        Vector3.up, 
        upness
        );

dynamiteRB.velocity = throwDirection * throwSpeed;
```

If you want to throw based on the camera, but want to adjust the angle from what the camera gives you, you can base the direction off of `Camera.main.transform` instead:

```
// give the dynamite a velocity so that it moves up + forward
Rigidbody dynamiteRB = Dyn.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

// 0f   = aim exact direction the camera is pointing
// 0.2f = aim slightly higher than camera is pointing
// 1f   = aim directly up
float additionalUpness = 0.0f; 
Vector3 throwDirection = Vector3.Slerp(
        Camera.main.transform.forward, 
        Vector3.up, 
        additionalUpness 
        );

dynamiteRB.velocity = throwDirection * throwSpeed;
```

Comment: That fixed it thanks! Is there anyway to attach it to the height that the camera is looking at, rather than a prefixed one?

Comment: @AdamSteele I edited my question to answer that. Briefly, you use `Camera.main.transform.forward` instead. I also changed it to use `Vector3.up` instead of `transform.up` so that you can't throw the dynamite behind you if you look up too much when throwing.